# Incorrect signature with RSA and SHA256

Tags: c++, .net, openssl, cryptography, rsa

I have the following string:`ET8d1voUkzNcqud7M8W0WQcd3l2Ih1ZtiMxStPeubKg=`

I want to apply SHA256 to it and obtain its hash.

Then I want to sign that hash with RSA and a private key.

This is the signature I'm suppose to be obtaining (without line breaks):

```
Zg8ftxJqRyoreMQtMKAZNrjHHcD/rOSkU29Ty8zV9aItwHBDO0WpzaaPrqnX6/vdayUAndDVvSBoOc9g0WBkFHQHtB/auLlq+ABeBP4jxy
d7ypPxBbJFecfZiBDaGCq4jAxUnhQ2HjT5R23DHOOcf/i50TrWXr2G5k8enqa754TUn1JiDOJJT2JkfnKmgM7EPpCjHV/eCJsOQFXNaxht
h7zHz5hZ4aOfy6EGGveOggzIjKSLeo0pIE8jBc1wy9V8vZkhPTpkeLguCxnwvpMIV1X7zF3m5OoM0PbC5yXgPUYPrz0JNSlvCKR9q5CsFm
rnit5vBfi5el1ZmevP2MgyEA==
```

This is the signature I get:

```
AR1X19H5wyb9IEi9WHrhatkR1jtTc7TovX23tdx8yID5CEWz+DF5kBNCXZxttJ8v
ctsbOL0rrQ0b4Gqa2ld00+nfzZJNg1osWwKb+sj6yNLy1XLqxFvfn1wrZ9Y8yOwS
oqJ0tTCpYbbbMo1mSVO4YuD18GbZJEDBUhBYY5D8H0MoHCSWLXsAjThAImyxw4ch
Hr2d1Sli4n6OA+CckGOQ15uLk6JiO6rNzNWfbbSb8a9trJ7bAdVPiKoln1X9tnWF
s3HK6fnfro9jlRQQ/Z0bCpF+FQrWrLouvLk+mjuTeiC+86HeeqzqlReAtpqtcO5/
9lWmrxXV2qZIqfuPYMovcA==
```

The code I'm using:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <openssl/aes.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstring>


std::string privateKey = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n"\
"MIIEogIBAAKCAQEAjdKXiqYHzi++YmEb9X6qvqFWLCz1VEfxom2JhinPSJxxcuZW\n"\
"Bejk2I5yCL5pDnUaG2xpQlMTkV/7S7JfGGvYJumKO4R5zg0QSA7qdxiEhcwf/ekf\n"\
"SvzM2EDnLHDCKAQwEWsnJy78uxZTLzu/65VZ7EgEcWUTvCs/GZJLI9s6XmKY2SMm\n"\
"v9+vfqBqkJNXE0ZB6OfSbyeE325P94iMn+B/yJ4vZwXvXGFqNDJyqG+ww7f77HYu\n"\
"bQPJjLQPedy2qTcgmSAwkUEJVBjYA6mPf/BeZlL1YJHHM7CIBnb3/bzED0n944wo\n"\
"io+4+rnMZdfhcCVpm74DZomlEf9KuJtq5u/JRQIDAQABAoIBAG2AzvWE4L346z02\n"\
"0cmptdhe5hRR2lLrAc1yWh83JQ9hi881vfHuMtRql+3cZ218SV4nRNarIo6612NJ\n"\
"JFfM3SaeZ9cwoIPSXmHk8nBmg9xzEbiRSVIzA09uPZB4t9EB+sNYQvDkPMuPn0b3\n"\
"EWaq+LWRnayYaLZ/hccOx+m1mcnJnIs27+EPnufrUKVniCguburQoU3VEXSFCzBk\n"\
"23rhSu20vUOikLuuU4gcvWfnfUoOwdhb2iBhjgMbsjTTmg3+GQuPtblCSTKjk11F\n"\
"YX2MJHEDFfwVzSurmbqAZC9rjr7PbflC8GMmPfa1LCb7IG5s9AIM4v9Fea0SyZP+\n"\
"/pM9mzkCgYEAyjLPU7ieqly9+mgeb2fmWh7pYgO49KuFIqqHnP+LaXXYK/TvCJ8X\n"\
"zJ3PxBgwVMOT94nXSDNjzNLzp0hl8OWWBH0tN0fiq1OEyySM3Mlji6o8KpGcU1k4\n"\
"jFkXMK1rVQcW8ckLmzMrQF3SphQi4UiEpLX1Zba4YQ4fNHK8NHHHaEMCgYEAs48m\n"\
"Oe4iEZcVDnag+Mp0Zjgu4mYJeeeGtVUZFCJOeyLDsQVmnt5mJIgGwrxg4o3qljut\n"\
"aAUXzf8aYZ0fURAsLcwnQg03THFKeIt94Rw/72n2UWT+AZTU3GQtuwf+osZHUfS3\n"\
"XTLaQE+A1JBC4XLJ99j/95sxt6xZy5YyfhfY09cCgYAbqyhDxJexqE823NiNViJn\n"\
"YqN9DhVZJb9qJvu3uCBTphSWr0WmYF7ZWR79LnIupzSwQuR6tM2LUbKVyYpplIEa\n"\
"zCZL0kJqP1uEkNPVwpkkm37wNEy3+xWJ3wcVWiW91OKG44P7EN1ySWRx5X+AZHQC\n"\
"NgQGjyJb5ZrPioPGiWtIEQKBgE/0B/N3o9ftTET6cccWbootDkNlaAbOH1+TGu2q\n"\
"MQQHgNfMLdvD7/uITmpb81AuHSz0Ocy9p9HkK90XV6CC8QkbhMeWlu8E60It6slY\n"\
"COgUaMfpjmkp2nagbPSBJNNaMtu9egCX6jMEs7ry2bUFpgUkrSWWB1df+UP8B1O6\n"\
"TqRVAoGAVQoCUPVm6C6h6V5dgPvsJMxJ8EjOCgwkXNucAHWcpBV3/LlxLiCGRuEL\n"\
"B+epYxqwKLpSQBhldasKmmKB0M6MFTwxXwxCmCi80+DBdP5A7GIK52ZGth63i22t\n"\
"FI8MeDIzA5HqAI24P7ltozoEYAB7GIdJQXq9oT/DRagTwQUzQ8E=\n"\
"-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n";

/*std::string privateKey ="-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n"\
"MIIEvAIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKYwggSiAgEAAoIBAQCN0peKpgfOL75i\n"\
"YRv1fqq+oVYsLPVUR/GibYmGKc9InHFy5lYF6OTYjnIIvmkOdRobbGlCUxORX/tL\n"\
"sl8Ya9gm6Yo7hHnODRBIDup3GISFzB/96R9K/MzYQOcscMIoBDARaycnLvy7FlMv\n"\
"O7/rlVnsSARxZRO8Kz8Zkksj2zpeYpjZIya/369+oGqQk1cTRkHo59JvJ4Tfbk/3\n"\
"iIyf4H/Ini9nBe9cYWo0MnKob7DDt/vsdi5tA8mMtA953LapNyCZIDCRQQlUGNgD\n"\
"qY9/8F5mUvVgkcczsIgGdvf9vMQPSf3jjCiKj7j6ucxl1+FwJWmbvgNmiaUR/0q4\n"\
"m2rm78lFAgMBAAECggEAbYDO9YTgvfjrPTbRyam12F7mFFHaUusBzXJaHzclD2GL\n"\
"zzW98e4y1GqX7dxnbXxJXidE1qsijrrXY0kkV8zdJp5n1zCgg9JeYeTycGaD3HMR\n"\
"uJFJUjMDT249kHi30QH6w1hC8OQ8y4+fRvcRZqr4tZGdrJhotn+Fxw7H6bWZycmc\n"\
"izbv4Q+e5+tQpWeIKC5u6tChTdURdIULMGTbeuFK7bS9Q6KQu65TiBy9Z+d9Sg7B\n"\
"2FvaIGGOAxuyNNOaDf4ZC4+1uUJJMqOTXUVhfYwkcQMV/BXNK6uZuoBkL2uOvs9t\n"\
"+ULwYyY99rUsJvsgbmz0Agzi/0V5rRLJk/7+kz2bOQKBgQDKMs9TuJ6qXL36aB5v\n"\
"Z+ZaHuliA7j0q4Uiqoec/4tpddgr9O8InxfMnc/EGDBUw5P3iddIM2PM0vOnSGXw\n"\
"5ZYEfS03R+KrU4TLJIzcyWOLqjwqkZxTWTiMWRcwrWtVBxbxyQubMytAXdKmFCLh\n"\
"SISktfVltrhhDh80crw0ccdoQwKBgQCzjyY57iIRlxUOdqD4ynRmOC7iZgl554a1\n"\
"VRkUIk57IsOxBWae3mYkiAbCvGDijeqWO61oBRfN/xphnR9RECwtzCdCDTdMcUp4\n"\
"i33hHD/vafZRZP4BlNTcZC27B/6ixkdR9LddMtpAT4DUkELhcsn32P/3mzG3rFnL\n"\
"ljJ+F9jT1wKBgBurKEPEl7GoTzbc2I1WImdio30OFVklv2om+7e4IFOmFJavRaZg\n"\
"XtlZHv0uci6nNLBC5Hq0zYtRspXJimmUgRrMJkvSQmo/W4SQ09XCmSSbfvA0TLf7\n"\
"FYnfBxVaJb3U4objg/sQ3XJJZHHlf4BkdAI2BAaPIlvlms+Kg8aJa0gRAoGAT/QH\n"\
"83ej1+1MRPpxxxZvKi0OQ2VoBs4fX5Ma7aoxBAeA18wt28Pv+4hOalvzUC4dLPQ5\n"\
"zL2n0eQr3RdXoILxCRuEx5aW7wTrQi3qyVgI6BRox+mOaSnadqBs9IEk01oy2716\n"\
"AJfqMwSzuvLZtQWmBSStJZYHV1/5Q/wHU7pOpFUCgYBVCgJQ9WboLqHpXl2A++wk\n"\
"zEnwSM4KDCRc25wAdZykFXf8uXEuIIZG4QsH56ljGrAoulJAGGV1qwqaYoHQzowV\n"\
"PDFfDEKYKLzT4MF0/kDsYgrnZka2HreLba0Ujwx4MjMDkeoAjbg/uW2jOgRgAHsY\n"\
"h0lBer2hP8NFqBPBBTNDwQ==\n"\
"-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
*/
std::string publicKey ="-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n"\
"MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAjdKXiqYHzi++YmEb9X6q\n"\
"vqFWLCz1VEfxom2JhinPSJxxcuZWBejk2I5yCL5pDnUaG2xpQlMTkV/7S7JfGGvY\n"\
"JumKO4R5zg0QSA7qdxiEhcwf/ekfSvzM2EDnLHDCKAQwEWsnJy78uxZTLzu/65VZ\n"\
"7EgEcWUTvCs/GZJLI9s6XmKY2SMmv9+vfqBqkJNXE0ZB6OfSbyeE325P94iMn+B/\n"\
"yJ4vZwXvXGFqNDJyqG+ww7f77HYubQPJjLQPedy2qTcgmSAwkUEJVBjYA6mPf/Be\n"\
"ZlL1YJHHM7CIBnb3/bzED0n944woio+4+rnMZdfhcCVpm74DZomlEf9KuJtq5u/J\n"\
"RQIDAQAB\n"\
"-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n";

RSA* createPrivateRSA(std::string key) {
  RSA *rsa = NULL;
  const char* c_string = key.c_str();
  BIO * keybio = BIO_new_mem_buf((void*)c_string, -1);
  if (keybio==NULL) {
      return 0;
  }
  rsa = PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey(keybio, &rsa,NULL, NULL);
  return rsa;
}

RSA* createPublicRSA(std::string key) {
  RSA *rsa = NULL;
  BIO *keybio;
  const char* c_string = key.c_str();
  keybio = BIO_new_mem_buf((void*)c_string, -1);
  if (keybio==NULL) {
      return 0;
  }
  rsa = PEM_read_bio_RSA_PUBKEY(keybio, &rsa,NULL, NULL);
  return rsa;
}

bool RSASign( RSA* rsa,
              const unsigned char* Msg,
              size_t MsgLen,
              unsigned char** EncMsg,
              size_t* MsgLenEnc) {
  EVP_MD_CTX* m_RSASignCtx = EVP_MD_CTX_create();
  EVP_PKEY* priKey  = EVP_PKEY_new();
  EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(priKey, rsa);
  if (EVP_DigestSignInit(m_RSASignCtx,NULL, EVP_sha256(), NULL,priKey)<=0) {
      return false;
  }
  if (EVP_DigestSignUpdate(m_RSASignCtx, Msg, MsgLen) <= 0) {
      return false;
  }
  if (EVP_DigestSignFinal(m_RSASignCtx, NULL, MsgLenEnc) <=0) {
      return false;
  }
  *EncMsg = (unsigned char*)malloc(*MsgLenEnc);
  if (EVP_DigestSignFinal(m_RSASignCtx, *EncMsg, MsgLenEnc) <= 0) {
      return false;
  }
  EVP_MD_CTX_free(m_RSASignCtx);
  return true;
}

bool RSAVerifySignature( RSA* rsa,
                         unsigned char* MsgHash,
                         size_t MsgHashLen,
                         const char* Msg,
                         size_t MsgLen,
                         bool* Authentic) {
  *Authentic = false;
  EVP_PKEY* pubKey  = EVP_PKEY_new();
  EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(pubKey, rsa);
  EVP_MD_CTX* m_RSAVerifyCtx = EVP_MD_CTX_create();

  if (EVP_DigestVerifyInit(m_RSAVerifyCtx,NULL, EVP_sha256(),NULL,pubKey)<=0) {
    return false;
  }
  if (EVP_DigestVerifyUpdate(m_RSAVerifyCtx, Msg, MsgLen) <= 0) {
    return false;
  }
  int AuthStatus = EVP_DigestVerifyFinal(m_RSAVerifyCtx, MsgHash, MsgHashLen);
  if (AuthStatus==1) {
    *Authentic = true;
    EVP_MD_CTX_free(m_RSAVerifyCtx);
    return true;
  } else if(AuthStatus==0){
    *Authentic = false;
    EVP_MD_CTX_free(m_RSAVerifyCtx);
    return true;
  } else{
    *Authentic = false;
    EVP_MD_CTX_free(m_RSAVerifyCtx);
    return false;
  }
}

void Base64Encode( const unsigned char* buffer,
                   size_t length,
                   char** base64Text) {
  BIO *bio, *b64;
  BUF_MEM *bufferPtr;

  b64 = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
  bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
  bio = BIO_push(b64, bio);

  BIO_write(bio, buffer, length);
  BIO_flush(bio);
  BIO_get_mem_ptr(bio, &bufferPtr);
  BIO_set_close(bio, BIO_NOCLOSE);
  BIO_free_all(bio);

  *base64Text=(*bufferPtr).data;
}

size_t calcDecodeLength(const char* b64input) {
  size_t len = strlen(b64input), padding = 0;

  if (b64input[len-1] == '=' && b64input[len-2] == '=') //last two chars are =
    padding = 2;
  else if (b64input[len-1] == '=') //last char is =
    padding = 1;
  return (len*3)/4 - padding;
}

void Base64Decode(const char* b64message, unsigned char** buffer, size_t* length) {
  BIO *bio, *b64;

  int decodeLen = calcDecodeLength(b64message);
  *buffer = (unsigned char*)malloc(decodeLen + 1);
  (*buffer)[decodeLen] = '\0';

  bio = BIO_new_mem_buf(b64message, -1);
  b64 = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
  bio = BIO_push(b64, bio);

  *length = BIO_read(bio, *buffer, strlen(b64message));
  BIO_free_all(bio);
}
unsigned char * strToHex(std::string plainText){
  unsigned char * hexArray;
  hexArray = (unsigned char*)malloc(plainText.length());
  for(int i = 0; i < plainText.size();i++){
    hexArray[i] = std::strtol(&plainText[i],NULL,64);
  }
  return hexArray;
}
char* signMessage(std::string privateKey, std::string plainText) {
  RSA* privateRSA = createPrivateRSA(privateKey);
  unsigned char* encMessage;
  char* base64Text;
  size_t encMessageLength;

  RSASign(privateRSA, (unsigned char*) plainText.data(), plainText.length(), &encMessage, &encMessageLength);
  Base64Encode(encMessage, encMessageLength, &base64Text);
  free(encMessage);
  return base64Text;
}

bool verifySignature(std::string publicKey, std::string plainText, char* signatureBase64) {
  RSA* publicRSA = createPublicRSA(publicKey);
  unsigned char* encMessage;
  size_t encMessageLength;
  bool authentic;
  Base64Decode(signatureBase64, &encMessage, &encMessageLength);
  bool result = RSAVerifySignature(publicRSA, encMessage, encMessageLength, plainText.c_str(), plainText.length(), &authentic);
  return result & authentic;
}

int main() {
  std::string plainText = "ET8d1voUkzNcqud7M8W0WQcd3l2Ih1ZtiMxStPeubKg=";

  char* signature = signMessage(privateKey, plainText);
  bool authentic = verifySignature(publicKey, "ET8d1voUkzNcqud7M8W0WQcd3l2Ih1ZtiMxStPeubKg=", signature);
  if ( authentic ) {
    std::cout << "Authentic" << std::endl;
    std::cout << signature << std::endl;
  } else {
    std::cout << "Not Authentic" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

What I'm actually trying to do is to 'translate' a C# code used by a third-party, I REQUIRE to do the same operations, I tried looking for the docs of the libreries used here but I couldn't find much, the code I'm trying to replicate is the following:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Security;



namespace KeyPairLoad
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string cadena = ComputeSha256Hash("ET8d1voUkzNcqud7M8W0WQcd3l2Ih1ZtiMxStPeubKg=");

            string pathPrivateKey = @"C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\Fieles de pruebas\FOO1\some.key";
            string password = "12345678a";

            byte[] privBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(pathPrivateKey);
            AsymmetricKeyParameter llavePrivada = PrivateKeyFactory.DecryptKey(password.ToCharArray(), privBytes);

            var rsaPriv = DotNetUtilities.ToRSA(llavePrivada as RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters);

            var csp = new CspParameters();
            csp.KeyContainerName = "KeyContainer";

            var rsaPrivate = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(csp);

            string fin = Convert.ToBase64String(rsaPrivate.SignHash(Convert.FromBase64String(cadena), "SHA256"));

        }
        static string ComputeSha256Hash(string rawData)
        {
            using (SHA256 sha256Hash = SHA256.Create())
            {
                byte[] bytes = sha256Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rawData));

                return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This third-party gave me the signature I'm supposed to be obtaining. I've tried many things but nothing works, I get different signatures but not the one I'm looking for.

Am I missing something in my translation? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for your patience and time. Let me know if u require more info.

Regards!

Comment: It goes without saying that you won't be using this particular private key for anything.

Comment: Yep, no worries it's just for testing purposes :3

Comment: Please can you clarify your question. In your question, and in the C code you state that the string you want to sign is "ET8d1voUkzNcqud7M8W0WQcd3l2Ih1ZtiMxStPeubKg". However in the .Net code the string you are operating on is "TextoconCadenaOriginalaFirmar" - which is obviously not the same string! Why?

Comment: The provided .NET code wasn't made by me, but you can pretend that we're signing the same string, I'll modify the question for you.

Comment: I can't produce either output using the C# code and private key you provided.  Can you please provide the value being hashed, in base64, the private key, in PEM and a minimal piece of code that can produce the signature that you are currently getting (not the one you want, obviously).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code gets the desired signature:

```
Zg8ftxJqRyoreMQtMKAZNrjHHcD/rOSkU29Ty8zV9aItwHBDO0WpzaaPrqnX6/vdayUAndDVvSBoOc9g0WBkFHQHtB/auLlq+ABeBP4jxy
d7ypPxBbJFecfZiBDaGCq4jAxUnhQ2HjT5R23DHOOcf/i50TrWXr2G5k8enqa754TUn1JiDOJJT2JkfnKmgM7EPpCjHV/eCJsOQFXNaxht
h7zHz5hZ4aOfy6EGGveOggzIjKSLeo0pIE8jBc1wy9V8vZkhPTpkeLguCxnwvpMIV1X7zF3m5OoM0PbC5yXgPUYPrz0JNSlvCKR9q5CsFm
rnit5vBfi5el1ZmevP2MgyEA==
```

that I originally stated. It writes it in a file called result.dat which I have to encode in base 64 resulting int he above signature.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <openssl/aes.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

#include "base64.h"

std::string privateKey = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
"MIIEogIBAAKCAQEAjdKXiqYHzi++YmEb9X6qvqFWLCz1VEfxom2JhinPSJxxcuZW\n"
"Bejk2I5yCL5pDnUaG2xpQlMTkV/7S7JfGGvYJumKO4R5zg0QSA7qdxiEhcwf/ekf\n"
"SvzM2EDnLHDCKAQwEWsnJy78uxZTLzu/65VZ7EgEcWUTvCs/GZJLI9s6XmKY2SMm\n"
"v9+vfqBqkJNXE0ZB6OfSbyeE325P94iMn+B/yJ4vZwXvXGFqNDJyqG+ww7f77HYu\n"
"bQPJjLQPedy2qTcgmSAwkUEJVBjYA6mPf/BeZlL1YJHHM7CIBnb3/bzED0n944wo\n"
"io+4+rnMZdfhcCVpm74DZomlEf9KuJtq5u/JRQIDAQABAoIBAG2AzvWE4L346z02\n"
"0cmptdhe5hRR2lLrAc1yWh83JQ9hi881vfHuMtRql+3cZ218SV4nRNarIo6612NJ\n"
"JFfM3SaeZ9cwoIPSXmHk8nBmg9xzEbiRSVIzA09uPZB4t9EB+sNYQvDkPMuPn0b3\n"
"EWaq+LWRnayYaLZ/hccOx+m1mcnJnIs27+EPnufrUKVniCguburQoU3VEXSFCzBk\n"
"23rhSu20vUOikLuuU4gcvWfnfUoOwdhb2iBhjgMbsjTTmg3+GQuPtblCSTKjk11F\n"
"YX2MJHEDFfwVzSurmbqAZC9rjr7PbflC8GMmPfa1LCb7IG5s9AIM4v9Fea0SyZP+\n"
"/pM9mzkCgYEAyjLPU7ieqly9+mgeb2fmWh7pYgO49KuFIqqHnP+LaXXYK/TvCJ8X\n"
"zJ3PxBgwVMOT94nXSDNjzNLzp0hl8OWWBH0tN0fiq1OEyySM3Mlji6o8KpGcU1k4\n"
"jFkXMK1rVQcW8ckLmzMrQF3SphQi4UiEpLX1Zba4YQ4fNHK8NHHHaEMCgYEAs48m\n"
"Oe4iEZcVDnag+Mp0Zjgu4mYJeeeGtVUZFCJOeyLDsQVmnt5mJIgGwrxg4o3qljut\n"
"aAUXzf8aYZ0fURAsLcwnQg03THFKeIt94Rw/72n2UWT+AZTU3GQtuwf+osZHUfS3\n"
"XTLaQE+A1JBC4XLJ99j/95sxt6xZy5YyfhfY09cCgYAbqyhDxJexqE823NiNViJn\n"
"YqN9DhVZJb9qJvu3uCBTphSWr0WmYF7ZWR79LnIupzSwQuR6tM2LUbKVyYpplIEa\n"
"zCZL0kJqP1uEkNPVwpkkm37wNEy3+xWJ3wcVWiW91OKG44P7EN1ySWRx5X+AZHQC\n"
"NgQGjyJb5ZrPioPGiWtIEQKBgE/0B/N3o9ftTET6cccWbootDkNlaAbOH1+TGu2q\n"
"MQQHgNfMLdvD7/uITmpb81AuHSz0Ocy9p9HkK90XV6CC8QkbhMeWlu8E60It6slY\n"
"COgUaMfpjmkp2nagbPSBJNNaMtu9egCX6jMEs7ry2bUFpgUkrSWWB1df+UP8B1O6\n"
"TqRVAoGAVQoCUPVm6C6h6V5dgPvsJMxJ8EjOCgwkXNucAHWcpBV3/LlxLiCGRuEL\n"
"B+epYxqwKLpSQBhldasKmmKB0M6MFTwxXwxCmCi80+DBdP5A7GIK52ZGth63i22t\n"
"FI8MeDIzA5HqAI24P7ltozoEYAB7GIdJQXq9oT/DRagTwQUzQ8E=\n"
"-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n";

// std::string privateKey ="-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n"\
// "MIIEvAIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKYwggSiAgEAAoIBAQCN0peKpgfOL75i\n"\
// "YRv1fqq+oVYsLPVUR/GibYmGKc9InHFy5lYF6OTYjnIIvmkOdRobbGlCUxORX/tL\n"\
// "sl8Ya9gm6Yo7hHnODRBIDup3GISFzB/96R9K/MzYQOcscMIoBDARaycnLvy7FlMv\n"\
// "O7/rlVnsSARxZRO8Kz8Zkksj2zpeYpjZIya/369+oGqQk1cTRkHo59JvJ4Tfbk/3\n"\
// "iIyf4H/Ini9nBe9cYWo0MnKob7DDt/vsdi5tA8mMtA953LapNyCZIDCRQQlUGNgD\n"\
// "qY9/8F5mUvVgkcczsIgGdvf9vMQPSf3jjCiKj7j6ucxl1+FwJWmbvgNmiaUR/0q4\n"\
// "m2rm78lFAgMBAAECggEAbYDO9YTgvfjrPTbRyam12F7mFFHaUusBzXJaHzclD2GL\n"\
// "zzW98e4y1GqX7dxnbXxJXidE1qsijrrXY0kkV8zdJp5n1zCgg9JeYeTycGaD3HMR\n"\
// "uJFJUjMDT249kHi30QH6w1hC8OQ8y4+fRvcRZqr4tZGdrJhotn+Fxw7H6bWZycmc\n"\
// "izbv4Q+e5+tQpWeIKC5u6tChTdURdIULMGTbeuFK7bS9Q6KQu65TiBy9Z+d9Sg7B\n"\
// "2FvaIGGOAxuyNNOaDf4ZC4+1uUJJMqOTXUVhfYwkcQMV/BXNK6uZuoBkL2uOvs9t\n"\
// "+ULwYyY99rUsJvsgbmz0Agzi/0V5rRLJk/7+kz2bOQKBgQDKMs9TuJ6qXL36aB5v\n"\
// "Z+ZaHuliA7j0q4Uiqoec/4tpddgr9O8InxfMnc/EGDBUw5P3iddIM2PM0vOnSGXw\n"\
// "5ZYEfS03R+KrU4TLJIzcyWOLqjwqkZxTWTiMWRcwrWtVBxbxyQubMytAXdKmFCLh\n"\
// "SISktfVltrhhDh80crw0ccdoQwKBgQCzjyY57iIRlxUOdqD4ynRmOC7iZgl554a1\n"\
// "VRkUIk57IsOxBWae3mYkiAbCvGDijeqWO61oBRfN/xphnR9RECwtzCdCDTdMcUp4\n"\
// "i33hHD/vafZRZP4BlNTcZC27B/6ixkdR9LddMtpAT4DUkELhcsn32P/3mzG3rFnL\n"\
// "ljJ+F9jT1wKBgBurKEPEl7GoTzbc2I1WImdio30OFVklv2om+7e4IFOmFJavRaZg\n"\
// "XtlZHv0uci6nNLBC5Hq0zYtRspXJimmUgRrMJkvSQmo/W4SQ09XCmSSbfvA0TLf7\n"\
// "FYnfBxVaJb3U4objg/sQ3XJJZHHlf4BkdAI2BAaPIlvlms+Kg8aJa0gRAoGAT/QH\n"\
// "83ej1+1MRPpxxxZvKi0OQ2VoBs4fX5Ma7aoxBAeA18wt28Pv+4hOalvzUC4dLPQ5\n"\
// "zL2n0eQr3RdXoILxCRuEx5aW7wTrQi3qyVgI6BRox+mOaSnadqBs9IEk01oy2716\n"\
// "AJfqMwSzuvLZtQWmBSStJZYHV1/5Q/wHU7pOpFUCgYBVCgJQ9WboLqHpXl2A++wk\n"\
// "zEnwSM4KDCRc25wAdZykFXf8uXEuIIZG4QsH56ljGrAoulJAGGV1qwqaYoHQzowV\n"\
// "PDFfDEKYKLzT4MF0/kDsYgrnZka2HreLba0Ujwx4MjMDkeoAjbg/uW2jOgRgAHsY\n"\
// "h0lBer2hP8NFqBPBBTNDwQ==\n"\
// "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";

std::string publicKey ="-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n"\
"MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAjdKXiqYHzi++YmEb9X6q\n"\
"vqFWLCz1VEfxom2JhinPSJxxcuZWBejk2I5yCL5pDnUaG2xpQlMTkV/7S7JfGGvY\n"\
"JumKO4R5zg0QSA7qdxiEhcwf/ekfSvzM2EDnLHDCKAQwEWsnJy78uxZTLzu/65VZ\n"\
"7EgEcWUTvCs/GZJLI9s6XmKY2SMmv9+vfqBqkJNXE0ZB6OfSbyeE325P94iMn+B/\n"\
"yJ4vZwXvXGFqNDJyqG+ww7f77HYubQPJjLQPedy2qTcgmSAwkUEJVBjYA6mPf/Be\n"\
"ZlL1YJHHM7CIBnb3/bzED0n944woio+4+rnMZdfhcCVpm74DZomlEf9KuJtq5u/J\n"\
"RQIDAQAB\n"\
"-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n";

RSA* createPrivateRSA(std::string key) {
  RSA *rsa = NULL;
  const char* c_string = key.c_str();
  BIO * keybio = BIO_new_mem_buf((void*)c_string, -1);
  if (keybio==NULL) {
      return 0;
  }
  rsa = PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey(keybio, &rsa,NULL, NULL);
  return rsa;
}

void sellar(std::string hashclear, std::string privateKey_string){

  EVP_PKEY_CTX *ctx;
  /* md is a SHA-256 digest in this example. */
  unsigned char *sig;
  size_t siglen;

  unsigned char clear_message[hashclear.length()];
  strcpy((char*) clear_message,hashclear.c_str());
  size_t mdlen;
  // //1. Decodificar hashclear. || base64 -d data.dat > b64.dat -> Me debe dar una cadena de 32 bytes.
  unsigned char * md = base64_decode(clear_message, strlen((char*) clear_message), &mdlen);
  std::cout << "MD is " << mdlen << " bytes long.\n";
  // //2. Cargar llave privada.
  RSA* privateRSA = createPrivateRSA(privateKey);
  EVP_PKEY* signing_key  = EVP_PKEY_new();

  EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(signing_key, privateRSA);

  ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(signing_key, NULL /* no engine */);
  if(!ctx) {
    std::cout << "Error CTX_new" << std::endl;
    return;
  }
  if (EVP_PKEY_sign_init(ctx) <= 0){
    std::cout << "Error sign_init\n";
    return;
  }
 if (EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_padding(ctx, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING) <= 0){
    std::cout << "Error set_rsa_padding\n";
    return;
 }
 if (EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_signature_md(ctx, EVP_sha256()) <= 0){
    std::cout << "Error set_signature_md\n";
    return;
 }

 /* Determine buffer length */
 if (EVP_PKEY_sign(ctx, NULL, &siglen, md, mdlen) <= 0){
    std::cout << "Error PKEY_sign\n";
    return;
 }
 sig = (unsigned char*)OPENSSL_malloc(siglen);

 if (!sig){
    std::cout << "Error malloc";
    return;
 }

 if (EVP_PKEY_sign(ctx, sig, &siglen, md, mdlen) <= 0){
    std::cout << "Error sign";
    return;
 }
 std::cout << siglen << " bytes written in buffer sig\n";
 /* Signature is siglen bytes written to buffer sig */
 size_t cadena_sellada_len;
 unsigned char * cadena_sellada = base64_encode(sig, siglen, &cadena_sellada_len);

 std::ofstream myfile ("result_final.dat");
 if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    for(int count = 0; count < cadena_sellada_len; count ++){
        myfile << cadena_sellada[count] ;
    }
    myfile.close();
  }
  else std::cout << "Unable to open file";
}

int main() {
  std::string plainText = "ET8d1voUkzNcqud7M8W0WQcd3l2Ih1ZtiMxStPeubKg=\n";
  // unsigned char src[plainText.length()];
  // strcpy((char*) src,plainText.c_str());
  // std::cout << "Src has " << strlen((char*)src) << " entries.\n";
  // size_t out_len;
  // unsigned char * bytes = base64_decode(src, strlen((char*)src), &out_len);
  // std::cout << "bytes has " << out_len << " entries.\n";
  // std::cout << bytes << std::endl;
  // size_t re_out_len;
  // unsigned char * re_encode = base64_encode(bytes, out_len,&re_out_len);
  // std::cout << re_encode << "\n";
  // std::ofstream myfile ("b64.dat");
  // if (myfile.is_open())
  // {
  //   for(int count = 0; count < out_len; count ++){
  //       myfile << bytes[count] ;
  //   }
  //   myfile.close();
  // }
  // else std::cout << "Unable to open file";

  sellar(plainText, privateKey);

  return 0;
  //strcpy()
  //std::cout << "Length : " << b64dat.length() << std::endl;
  //char* signature = signMessage(privateKey, plainText);

  //std::cout << signature << std::endl;
  // bool authentic = verifySignature(publicKey, "ET8d1voUkzNcqud7M8W0WQcd3l2Ih1ZtiMxStPeubKg=", signature);
  // if ( authentic ) {
  //   std::cout << "Authentic" << std::endl;

  // } else {
  //   std::cout << "Not Authentic" << std::endl;
  // }
}
```

Thank you all for your time and patience.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to read all the code to try and figure out what it is you're trying to do and thus where your mistake(s) are. Instead, I'll just examine what you've provided and you can go from there.

Clearly, both the signatures you've provided are valid signatures. This can be seen by manually going through the verification steps, stopping just after modular exponentiation using the encrypt exponent. The result is as expected for [pkcs1 EMSA-PKCS1-v1_5 encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-9.2). And just as clearly, we can see that different SHA-256 hashes are involved. In other words, the signatures are different because the data they are signing is different.

For the signature that starts with `AR1X19...` the data being signed is the UTF-8 encoding of the string `ET8d1voUkzNcqud7M8W0WQcd3l2Ih1ZtiMxStPeubKg=`. Note that this string a pretty obviously the base64-encoding of random looking 32 bytes. In this context one might guess that those 32-bytes are actually the sha256 hash of some other unknown quantity. And sure, enough the signature that starts with `Zg8ftxJqR...` is over data whose sha256 hash is the base64-decoding of `ET8d...`.

So it looks like the first signature is correct, and the second one is the result of base64-encoding the sha256 hash during in the middle of the signing operation.

Comment: So you're saying that if I base64-encode the AR1X19... signature I will get the Zg8ftx... signature?

Comment: @DavidMerinos: No, that's not what I'm saying. I'm saying that if you sha256 hash the real message, then base64-encode the result, you'll get `ET8d1...`. The `AR1X...` is the result of signing `ET8d..`, which is the result of a bug in your code.

Comment: But I want to sign `ET8d1voUkzNcqud7M8W0WQcd3l2Ih1ZtiMxStPeubKg=` and I'm supposed to obtain the signature starting with `Zg8ftxJqRyoreMQtMKAZNrjHHcD...`,

Comment: How to obtain that? I do not fully understand your response :(

Comment: You were right, I was hashing again. OpenSSL docs are a pain in the ass but I got it done. Thanks